# matchRegex function example in Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell

Hi I am getting Text responses and I want to match them using Regex and apply the necessary function
For instance suppose if I get a text
"34n5n5: What is the result of 5 plus 0" I pass it to a function to get required output

How do I use the [matchRegex](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.92/docs/Text-Regex.html) function in haskell to match this Text.
If there is a better way to match then please tell that also.

For example for this request

"34n5n5: What is the result of 5 plus 0"

Here "34n5n5" can be different for different requests

The numbers (5 0) can change

Comment: If you would show us some Haskell (even if completely wrong) this would give us a better idea of what exactly you are asking, and what exactly you don't understand about [matchRegex](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.92/docs/Text-Regex.html). It might even make you find the answer yourself!

Comment: Actually I have figured it out. I am using Test.Regix.Posix. This will return true if the input string matches

(x =~ " what is [0-9]* plus [0-9]*" ::Bool)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Posting it here for the benefit of others

I am using `Text.Regix.Posix`. This will return `True` if the input string matches:

```
x = "34n5n5: What is 5 plus 0"
result = (x =~ " what is [0-9]* plus [0-9]*" ::Bool)
```

will bind `result` to `True`